# [networkx]double-edges-swap

Tags: networkx

```
# Instead of choosing uniformly at random from a generated edge list,
# this algorithm chooses nonuniformly from the set of nodes with
# probability weighted by degree.
程序中选择的方法和从边列表中随机选相比，有什么优势？
```

还有，connected_double_edge_swap(G, nswap=1, _window_threshold=3)
    _window_threshold是什么？
   保持连通性不应该是对连通子图进行保证连通性的断边重连吗？

Comment: Please,  use english on StackOverflow.

Comment: 1.why author use the algorithm choosing nonuniformly from the set of nodes with probability weighted by degree, without choosing uniformly at random from a generated edge list?

Comment: You can edit post directly, and help people ask your question.

Comment: Feel free to edit you question. Also you can add tags "python" and "graphs". Also add link to documentation of function you asking. This will help users to answer your question.

Comment: Please let me know if I've correctly interpreted your question.  If so I'll edit your question to be in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your question is:

> The source code of `nx.double_edge_swap` says:
>
> > Instead of choosing uniformly at random from a generated edge list,
> >         this algorithm chooses nonuniformly from the set of nodes with
> >         probability weighted by degree.
>
> Why did they decide to do it this way?"

Is that correct?

If so, then first I'll explain why the two methods give the same result.  Conceptually, we want to create a large list of edges and then randomly choose two edges from that list.  If we instead choose two nodes with probability proportional to its degree, and then choose one edge from each node, we've accomplished the same result:

If `u` has `c` times as many edges as `v`, let's let `p_v` be the probability of choosing `v` and `d_v` its degree.  Then the probability of choosing a given edge from `v` is `p_v/d_v`: that is the probability of choosing `v` times `1/d_v`, the probability of choosing that edge.  Now let's look at one of `u`'s edges:  Its probability of being chosen is `cp_v/cd_v` which is the same.

Now why do it this way rather than creating a long list of edges?  One issue is memory constraints.  To choose from all edges would require having all edges in memory in a list or a set.  This would be difficult.  A second issue is that once the edges swap, not only would we have to update the graph, but we'd have to update this list or set, which may not be an efficient process.  So there would be more code being written and more steps being taken.

Comment: I failed to understand your words that   the probability of choosing a given edge from v is p_v/d_v: that is the probability of choosing v times 1/d_v, the probability of choosing that edge . Can i think that  d_v equals to the number of edges contain the node v. now we supose the len(G.edges())=m, so p_v=d_v/m. that means 1/m=p_v/d_v, that is the probability of choosing a given edge from v. That's right?